# Solving $\int_0^{+\infty}\,k^{-1}\,J_1(kR)\,J_1(ka)\,\exp(-d^2k^2)\,dk$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

I am trying to solve the following integral:

$$I(a,R,d)=\int_0^{+\infty}\,k^{-1}\,J_1(kR)\,J_1(ka)\,\exp(-d^2k^2)\,dk$$

where $J_1(x)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and $R,a,d$ have real positive values.

Playing with some numbers it's easy to check that the integral is convergent ([see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+besselj%5B1%2C2%2ax%5D%2abesselj%5B1%2C3%2ax%5D%2F%28x%29%2aexp%28-x%5E2%29%2C+from+0+to+500)).

I tried to apply an integral from G&R's book (page 707, 6.633/1):

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\,x^{\lambda+1}\,J_{\mu}(\beta x)\,J_{\nu}(\gamma x)\,\exp(-\alpha x^2)\,dx=\frac{\beta^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\alpha^{-\frac{\nu+\mu+\lambda+2}{2}}}{2^{\nu+\mu+1}\Gamma(\nu+1)}\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\Gamma(m+1+0.5(\nu+\mu+\lambda))}{m!\Gamma(m+\mu+1)}\left(-\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\right)^m\,F\left(-m,-\mu-m;\nu+1;\frac{\gamma^2}{\beta^2}\right)$$

valid for $Re(\nu+\mu+\lambda)>-2$.

In my case $\nu=\mu=1$ and $\lambda=-2$ (that is $Re(\nu+\mu+\lambda)=0>-2$), therefore I have:

$$I(a,R,d)=\frac{aR}{8d^2}\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(m+1)!}\left(-\frac{R^2}{4d^2}\right)^m\,F\left(-m,-1-m;2;\frac{a^2}{R^2}\right)$$

Does anyone know how to simplify further the solution???

A simmetry issue ($\nu=\mu$) allows me to state that (does it really help?):

$$\frac{aR}{8d^2}\left(-\frac{R^2}{4d^2}\right)^m\,F\left(-m,-1-m;2;\frac{a^2}{R^2}\right)=\frac{aR}{8d^2}\left(-\frac{a^2}{4d^2}\right)^m\,F\left(-m,-1-m;2;\frac{R^2}{a^2}\right)$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A closed form for the integral involves a two variables hypergeometric series (Attachment). This is a special function of the Appell hypergeometric kind.
I doubt that a simpler special function be convenient. Unfortunately, this is not a breakthrough compared to your own approach.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not help. In principle you can get the same final result by using the series representation of bessel functions and calculate the [gaussian integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html) (something like $\int_0^{+\infty}\,k^{2(m+n)+1}\exp(-d^2k^2)\,dk$).

Comment: Of course, it doesn't help if the expected result is a formula where only a finite number of standard functions are involved. Moreover, the relation with the Laplace transforms which doesn't leads to simpler expression, draw to think that a closed form involving functions of lower level might not exist.